# SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod has no effect with SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED

Tags: c, opacity, sdl-2

### Context

I have an image loaded with SDL2. I can display it without any problem with `SDL_RenderCopy` or `SDL_RenderCopyEx`. I want now to change the opacity of my image.

### What I tried

I tried using `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod` according to the documentation.

```
SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(my_texture, 122);
```

It was not working. I tried to put it before `SDL_RenderClear`, after `SDL_RenderClear` and even after `SDL_RenderCopy`. None of these worked.

After that, I tried to change my renderer from `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` to `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` and... it worked. However, it's obviously slower than with `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`.

I have to add that I don't have any error with `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`. No error but no result.

### What I want to do

I want a way to change the opacity of my image with `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED` instead of `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE`.

**EDIT:**

I tried using `SDL_Image` and now I only have issues when loading a BMP image. I think I should convert the BMP into another format. Any idea?

I have the issue on both Windows and Linux and I'm using SDL 2.0.5.

Comment: Did you check the returned value of `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod`? "Alpha modulation is not always supported by the renderer; it will return -1 if alpha modulation is not supported." https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod

Comment: As I said in the post, I checked: "I have to add that I don't have any error with `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`."

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  OS?  SDL_Renderer backend?  SDL2 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to add:

```
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(my_texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
```

To get it working with any image, before setting `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod`.